# Adding motion blur to a video sequence

Tags: rendering, motion-blur

I am wondering whether it would be possible to use Blender to add a simulated rolling shutter motion blur to a video sequence.

I have a video sequence, taken at 240 FPS with a global shutter camera. I would like to use this video to generate a 30 FPS video with a realistic rolling shutter motion blur.

Can Blender help with this?

Comment: A simple test with a high fps overlaid with a moving cube and hastily rendered shows that cycles motion blur has no effect on the video, sadly http://pasteboard.co/ovDVlgqVF.gif

Comment: The same with blender internal, although I expected a different outcome due to the sampled nature of the blur http://pasteboard.co/ovIFRcRGw.gif

Comment: I was just browsing blender.se and found this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2apg86PNTlw linked to this question http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71400/motion-trail-effect-on-video-in-vse Don't know whether it's a rolling shutter though